# How do I check if a C# generic type is a collection (IEnumerable)?

Tags: c#, linq, generics

I'm trying to create a method with generic parameters:

```
public List<DTListItem> MapDTListResponse(List<App.Order.DT> dtList)
{
    return dtList.Select(MapDTListResponse).ToList();
}

public DTListItem MapDTListResponse(App.Order.DT dt)
{
    return RecMap<DTListItem, App.Order.DT>(dt);
}

private T RecMap<T,TU>(TU newObject)
{
    if (TU is IEnumerable) // this doesn't work; what do i check for here
    {
        //Also, how do i get this bit to replicate MapDTListReponse
        newObject.Select(RecMap).ToList();  
    } 
    else 
    {
        return Mapper.Map<T>(newObject);
    }            
}
```

As you can see, the first method takes and returns a collection and simply calls the second method (having the same name but different signature) for each element in the collection.

I want to create a generic method which will handle both cases. It should call itself if a collection is passed through. For this I need to check if the type is `IEnumerable` but the line `T is IEnumerable` has the following error

> TU is a type which is not valid in the given context.

Also, `newObject.Select(Map).ToList();` has the following error

> TU does not contain a definition for Select

Answer (score 2):

The `is` operator takes an object instance on its left hand side, so it can't be used like that. Instead, you can do this:

```
if (newObject is IEnumerable) // ...
```

And because you want to use the instance as a collection later on, you can use the `as` operator instead:

```
var newCollection = newObject as IEnumerable<T>;
if (newCollection != null) // ...
```

Worth pointing out that in cases where all you have is a type (and not an instance), you can achieve the same thing through the `IsAssignableFrom` method of the `Type` class, like this:

```
public static bool IsSequence<T>() => typeof(IEnumerable).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T));
```

Comment: Thanks, that seems to have helped. I've changed my `if` loop to `if (typeof(IEnumerable).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(TU)))`, but it's still not letting me call the `IEnumerable.select` method against it (second part of my question).

Comment: After I've cast `TU` as `IEnumerable` the error beneath the `select` disappears but I've no way to replicate the functionality of the first method since it now tries to to return a `List<T>`. I'm guessing there's no way to do this in a single method.